# How can I list all foreign key related objects in Django admin panel?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I would like to implement a very simple feature with the django admin panel but I couldn't find the right way to achieve this so far:

model.py

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Books(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
```

admin.py

```
class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
admin.site.register(Author, AuthorAdmin)
```

How can I add a hyperlink to every item (Author) in the authors' list overview that links to a view showing all books of the specific author? For Example:

- J.K. Rowling (books)
- J.R.R. Tolkien (books)

where books is a hyperlink to a site showing all books of the author.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for a [ModelAdmin.list_filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter).

Set list_filter to activate filters in the right sidebar of the change list page of the admin. A listfilter can be a field name, where the specified field should be either a BooleanField, CharField, DateField, DateTimeField, IntegerField, ForeignKey or ManyToManyField, for example:

```
 # Add a list filter author to BookAdmin.
 # Now you can filter books by author.
 class BookAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ('author', )
```

Now you can use @Wolph suggestion to add a link in the Author list_display. This link points to the book list filtered by author:

```
# Add hyperlinks to AuthorAdmin.
# Now you can jump to the book list filtered by autor. 
class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def authors(self):
        return '<a href="/admin/appname/book/?author__id__exact=%d">%s</a>' % (self.author_id, self.author)
    authors.allow_tags = True
```

ALTERNATIVE. To save a click you can also point to the change view of a book directly:

```
class Books(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)

def get_admin_url(self):
    return "/admin/appname/books/%d/" %self.id


class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def authors(self):
        html = ""
        for obj in Books.objects.filter(author__id_exact=self.id):
            html += '<p><a href="%s">%s</a></p>' %(obj.get_admin_url(), obj.title)
        return html
    authors.allow_tags = True

    list_display = ['title', authors]
```

Disclaimer: Not tested, but if you fix the typo's it'll work! :)

Note that these links can also be injected at other points in the admin. When you add it to a widget, you can go from change view to change view.

Comment: thanks for the answer. What changes do I have to make on the 'Books' side to get this working? Currently the result still includes all books in the database (of course).

Comment: My bad. List filter is on the BookAdmin. See update.

Comment: with authors.allow_tags = True it works finally :) Last question regarding this issue: Can you tell me how I can replace '/admin/appname/book/' by an urlresolver?

Comment: No, I never used a url resolver in this case. Since I only use it in the admin which structure is based on models and therefore doesn't change much. But if you want to make this more dynamic, than you can investigate a model property to create the author links https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/models/#model-methods And have a look at how Django constructs related_name attributes. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name "%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related". But maybe there are better ways.

Answer (score 9):

Look into implementing an [InlineModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) object.

```
# admin.py
class BooksInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Books

class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [BooksInline]
```

Edited answer in response to OP's comment:

```
class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'books_published']

    def books_published(self, obj):
        redirect_url = reverse('admin:books_changelist')
        extra = "?author__id__exact=%d" % (obj.id)
        return "<a href='%s'>Books by author</a>" % (redirect_url + extra)

    books_published.allow_tags = True
```

Comment: When I understand InlineModelAdmin correctly, it is for editing and adding purposes of books inside of an author form. I'm looking for an List-Overview of the books only

Comment: thanks for the edit. What changes do I have to make on the 'Books' side to get this working? Currently the result still includes all books in the database (of course).

Comment: The "extra" variable in the code should be filtering the queryset returned on the changelist page for a single author.  Are all your books by the same author?  You may have to tweak the string value slightly if I have a typo somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

It's not as simple as you might think actually, possible but not trivial since there is not that much documentation of this feature :)

What you need is a custom column which is generated by a function which gives you a link to the Django admin with a given filter. Something like this (from the top of my head so not tested) should do the trick:

```
class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def authors(self):
        return '<a href="?author=%d">%s</a>' % (self.author_id, self.author)
    authors.allow_html = True

    list_display = ['title', authors]
```