# Listing foreign keys related to a proxy model in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

My models.py looks like this :

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class DraftBooks(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    status_choices = ((1,Draft),(2,Published))
    status = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=status_choices)

class PubBooks(DraftBooks):
    class meta:
        proxy = True
        verbose name = 'Published Books'
```

I am using a proxy model since I want a different change list view for books in draft state and books which have been published.To achieve this,my admin.py looks like this :

```
class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
admin.site.register(Author, AuthorAdmin)

class DraftBooksAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   list_display = ('title','author','status')
   def queryset(self):
        return DraftBooks.objects.filter(status='1')
admin.site.register(DraftBooks, DraftBooksAdmin) 

class PubBooksAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title','author','status')
    def queryset(self):
        return PubBooks.objects.filter(status='2')
admin.site.register(PubBooks, PubBooksAdmin)
```

This setup works perfectly fine.In my admin,now I have 3 change list views,one which shows a list of all authors,one which shows book which are in a draft state and finally one which shows the list of books which are in a published state.

I now need to add a hyperlink to every item (Author) in the authors' list overview that links to a view showing all books of the specific authors.For Example:

1. J.K. Rowling (books)
2. J.R.R. Tolkien (books)

where books is a hyperlink to a site showing all books of a particular author.
Now I am completely clueless as to how to do this.[Django Xadmin](https://github.com/sshwsfc/django-xadmin/blob/master/xadmin/plugins/relate.py) has a plugin which provides just this feature.[This Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096305/how-can-i-list-all-foreign-key-related-objects-in-django-admin-panel) question also provides answer to this problem.But the problem is that they do not work in proxy models with the custom filters that I have.When I try to get the list of books by an author,I get only the books which are in Draft state.I would ideally want all the books,Draft and Published by an author.How do i achieve this ?