# Pagination hack for Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

My models.py looks like this :

```
class Change(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Editor = models.ForeignKey(editor)
    Choices = ((1,"Pending"),(2,"In Progress",),(3,"Closed"))
    Status = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=Choices, default=1, max_length=1)
```

I have lots of changes so I am using pagination to list the changes in the django admin.The per page pagination limit is 200.However,what I want to do is to ensure that the first page in the change list view on the admin site contains only changes in the Pending and In Progress state or in other words no change in the Closed state should be on the first page.Is there some function that I can use in my admin.py file to achieve this ?

Comment: Why don't you use filters instead?

Comment: There is no built-in mechanism to apply a filter just to the first page of a list view, but theoretically the admin is just another Django application, albeit a rather complex one - so you can write a custom paginator and override the default for a particular list view.

Comment: You can create a proxy model for `Change`, register it in admin and  use filtered `QuerySet` in its listing, which will show only records matching your criteria.

Comment: i had created a proxy class called ClosedChanges and used Queryset to filter changes in Closed state .The problem is that I have a Foreign key(see edit) in the Change model .In this case, I have a need to list all changes done by an Editor.I used the function found [here](https://github.com/sshwsfc/django-xadmin/blob/master/xadmin/plugins/relate.py#L42) to perform this.However,it performs the query only on the base model and omits the proxy model.See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23873751/listing-foreign-keys-related-to-a-proxy-model-in-django-admin) for more details.

Comment: If you could let me know what changes can I make in `reverse('%s:%s_%s_changelist' % (
          self.admin_site.app_name, label, model_name)),` to ensure that not only the base model but also the proxy model is used while performing the query,then I no longer need the pagination hack