# In Django admin, what's the easiest way to display a list of objects not relationally bound on an edit form?

Tags: django, django-admin

On the edit form of a model, I would like to display a list of other objects from a model that is not relationally bound to this object, but does have a field I want to look up based on a value in this model. I would preferably like that 2nd model to display as a list the same way it does on the list view for that model, only filtering a subset based on a particular value on the primary model. It is not required to be able to edit any of the fields of the other model, and actually that is not preferable.

Is there an easy way to do this in the admin.py without having to mess with admin templates?

Comment: Is there a foreign key that relates the two models?  Or what is the relationship?

Comment: No @joelgoldstick , that's why I said they are not relationally bound. I'm more interested in how to display the results then how to do the lookup.

Comment: Not completely sure what your use case is. Maybe you can do this with a custom field. So, no easy way :-(.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar question here: [How can I list all foreign key related objects in Django admin panel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096305/how-can-i-list-all-foreign-key-related-objects-in-django-admin-panel), and I modified it to work on the change forms.

```
class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ()

    def choices(self, instance):
        html = ''
        choice_list = Choice.objects.all().filter(question=instance)
        for obj in choice_list:
            html += '<p>%s</p>' % obj.choice_text
        return html

    choices.allow_tags = True

    def get_readonly_fields(self, requst, obj=None):
        if obj:
            return self.readonly_fields + ('choices',)
        return self.readonly_fields
```

What is happening is that to add the information to the form, it has to be read-only. So the get_readonly_fields method adds the choices field into the admin when it is changing the object only. When the choices are loaded, it searches by whatever criteria you would like, and displays them as HTML.

The models are based off of the django tutorial on the djangoproject, but I can send you the full app if you would like.

Comment: I updated one of my projects to use this strategy: https://github.com/zmetcalf/daily_emailer/blob/master/daily_emailer/admin.py#L57