# In Django-admin, how to add filter or search for foreign key select box?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I got a `foreign key` model with about 100,000 date.

It's too difficult to select the wanted data. So I'm wondering if there is a humanized way to add `foreign key` in django admin.

I have tried the `raw_id_fields`, it's useless.

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096305/how-can-i-list-all-foreign-key-related-objects-in-django-admin-panel) don't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I list all foreign key related objects in Django admin panel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096305/how-can-i-list-all-foreign-key-related-objects-in-django-admin-panel)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Select2](https://select2.github.io/) is very handy to deal with such situation. You may check packages for Select2 integration with Django.

[django-select2](https://github.com/codingjoe/django-select2) and [django-easy-select2](https://github.com/asyncee/django-easy-select2) both are good option to consider.

Comment: Thanks, seems this is what I want.But I can't get it work, btw, I use grappelli, having tried `grappelli-filter`, but does not take effect.

Comment: Smart! `django-easy-select2` works and easy enough for a backend coder.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a `raw_id_fields` set on your source admin class, you can set the `search_fields` on the target admin model to be able to filter the result based on the set `search_fields`, i.e. you will get a search input field in the select list popup, see image below.

[image]

Alternatively, django-2.0 just merged a pull request providing support for using select2 widgets in the django admin, see pull request for the full list of supported fields: https://github.com/django/django/pull/6385

With this you can use the `autocomplete_fields` on a `foreignkey` field on your source admin class and as before set the `search_fields` on the target admin class.

[image]