# List all children of a parent in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I am looking to switch from web2py to django. That is why I am trying out Django.
Lets say I have parents and children in a sql database. A one-to-many relationship. In Django admin I now can list all the parents, being able to add,edit and delete them. In the list of the parents I would like to add a button for each parent that, when clicked, redirects me to a list of all the children belonging to it.

In web2py there is a cool prebuilt way of doing it, which looks like this:
http://www.web2py.com/books/default/image/35/en6800.png

In a way a button, that redirects you to the list of all children
(what Django already is able to do - listing all children),
only that the children are secretly filtered by the chosen parent.

Is there a way to do this in Django?

Thanks for you help and have a great weekend
schnubby

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I list all foreign key related objects in Django admin panel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096305/how-can-i-list-all-foreign-key-related-objects-in-django-admin-panel)